# Setting a value-only attribute and not a key-value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add a single word attribute to an object.

Should be: `<option selected>aaa</option>`

Not:       `<option selected="selected">aaa</option>`

Using jQuery or javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<option selected>` is just HTML shorthand for `<option selected="selected">`. When you view a  webpage, your browser will convert the HTML into a DOM (which doesn't care which syntax was used to create it). You can then manipulate the DOM (this is important, you are not manipulating the original HTML, just what the browser has parsed it into).

If you ever serialise the DOM back to HTML then you might get `<option selected>` or `<option selected="selected">` depending on how the serializer was implemented. You will probably do this by asking the browser to provide the `innerHTML` of an element, in which case which you get is determined by the browser authors and you have no control over it.

If it is important to express the selected attribute using the shorthand form, then you will have to use an alternative seraliser that gives you that control. I'm not aware of any, so you might have to write something from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.setAttribute("blah","")
```

That should do it.

Comment: An empty string is not a valid value for the selected attribute. Browsers will perform error recovery (probably by either assuming you meant `setAttribute('selected', 'selected')` or `removeAttribute('selected')`.

Comment: @Quentin granted, but we're talking about nonstandard attributes anyhow.  Any behavior is unpredictable at best because adding such attributes is not standardized.  In chrome it worked as expected.  Any other browser, idk.

Comment: Why are we talking about non-standard attributes? The question uses entirely standard ones.

Comment: @Quentin lol wow... this whole time I was thinking that selected was a non-standard convention. XD  oh well... in that case I would have to say your answer is correct. :P You just shouldn't try to have the selected attribute without a value.

Answer (score 0):

Use Property.

This changes the currently selected

```
$(selector).prop('selected',true);
```

http://api.jquery.com/prop/

**EDIT:**

http://jsfiddle.net/DH9ac/1/

This changes the defaultSelected

```
$(selector).prop('defaultSelected',true);
```

This will now set the default select value, but with the extended format: selected="selected".

Comment: Tested in Chrome. It didn't add any selected attribute at all.

Comment: For me neither. Maybe because the option is not inside a <form>

Comment: .prop is really new thing. It came on jQuery 1.6. Are you using the newer version?

Comment: If I wasn't using a version of jQuery with `prop` then it would have errored before alerting the HTML. And the presence of a `<form>` makes no difference. http://jsfiddle.net/bkuKU/

Comment: (This is because, BTW, the selected attribute sets a default value while the selected property sets the current value)

Comment: Yeh, just noticed that aswell in my own experiment: http://jsfiddle.net/DH9ac/ The question itself doesn't really tell where the answer will be used for. He wanted to have short notation but now there isnt any notation at all. Hehe